# How to change the value of a QString global variable in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, global-variables, extern

I'm trying to implement a way for users to change the function of a button that replaces regex matches within text.

As an example input I'm using "(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d)|(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)|(\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d\d\d)" which works elsewhere in the code.

The issue is that when I try to change or initialize userDefinedClean or userDefinedInsert (both global QString) the new value isn't stored.

Here's the relevant code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <iostream>

#define TEXTEDIT  ui -> textEdit
#define TITLECHANGE(x, y) this->setWindowTitle("DataOrganiser: " + x.remove(0,y))
#define HOMEPATH QDir::homePath()
#define TEMPFILEPATH HOMEPATH + "/Desktop/QT stuff/Data Organiser/DataOrganiser/Temporary.txt"

QString fileInUse = TEMPFILEPATH;
QString userFilePath = HOMEPATH + "/Documents/UserFiles";

QString userDefinedClean;
QString userDefinedInsert;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

```
void MainWindow::on_action_Clean_Settings_triggered()
{
    QLabel *textLabel = new QLabel(this);
    textLabel->setFrameStyle(QFrame::StyledPanel | QFrame::Raised);
    QPushButton *textButton = new QPushButton(userFilePath);
    bool ok;
    bool okk;

    QString cleanText = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Current regex:" + userDefinedClean,
                                             "New Regex:", QLineEdit::Normal, "", &ok);
    QString insertText = QInputDialog::getText(this, "Current regex:" + userDefinedInsert,
                                               "New value:", QLineEdit::Normal, "", &okk);
    if (ok && okk && !cleanText.isEmpty()) {
        userDefinedClean = cleanText;
        userDefinedInsert = insertText;
    }
}
```

---

```
void MainWindow::on_cleanButton_clicked()
{
    QString text = TEXTEDIT -> toPlainText();
    QString search;
    text.replace("  ", " "); text.replace("   ", " "); text.replace("    ", " "); // this should be user customisable

    if(userDefinedClean != "") {
        QRegularExpression check1(userDefinedClean);
        QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchs = check1.globalMatch(text);
        while(matchs.hasNext()) {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchs.next();
            search = match.captured(0);
            text.replace(search, userDefinedInsert);
        }
    }

    TEXTEDIT -> clear();
    TEXTEDIT -> insertHtml(text);
}
```

*relevant part of the header*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include "qtextedit.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

extern QString userDefinedClean;
extern QString userDefinedInsert;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You haven't described the problem. Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Sorry, changed the question to be more coherent, and to actually state the question that my tired self forgot to ask.

Comment: From what you have shown, the only place userDefinedClean gets set to anything is in the on_action_Clean_Settings_triggered function. Are you sure you're getting to that line of code?

Comment: yes, I went through the debugger and saw that those lines were executed.

Comment: What value is getting set there? And how do you know "the new value isn't stored"?